# WPF - trouble with bold fonts

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

[image]

the attached screen shot should give you a good idea what i am talking about. i wrote a small wpf app that can create a 'postcard' using any image i choose. it can then save the image with or without text to a jpg which can then be emailed. i take the following steps:

1. bring up the text entry form (pictured)
2. click on the Font button which allows me to choose (or change) the font name, size and color.
3. if i don't select bold, the form comes out looking like the screen shot (correct).
4. my problem comes in when i try adding text with a bold font to the entry box and (via binding), the postcard text.

what happens is the weight of the font in the label and all 3 buttons changes to bold when the textbox should be the only control affected. only the weight is changing - the font name, size and color remain as they were.
it's driving me crazy. can't figure it out. i've included what i think is the relevant code.

xaml from form:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PostcardMVVM.Views.EditView" Style="{StaticResource ControlStyle}"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PostcardMVVM.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="800" Height="640" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

<!--<UserControl.DataContext>
    <editModel:EditViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>-->

<!--<Grid>
    <Border Margin="68,67,60,67" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" Margin="37,89,118,98" />
    </Border>
</Grid>-->

<Grid>
    <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="SlateGray" BlurRadius="10"/>
    </Grid.Effect>
    <Canvas x:Name="mainGrid" Margin="0,0,0,200" Background="White">
        <Image x:Name="imgvImage" Height="400" Width="400" Canvas.Left="255" Canvas.Top="20"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tblkText" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="210" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20"  
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=txtText, Path=Foreground}"  Width="400" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtText, Path=Text}" Padding="10, 3, 10, 3" 
            FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=txtText, Path=FontFamily}" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=txtText, Path=FontSize}"  FontWeight="{Binding ElementName=txtText, Path=FontWeight}" 
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.238,-2.2" Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Color="Black" BlurRadius="3" ></DropShadowEffect>
            </TextBlock.Effect>
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform >
                <RotateTransform Angle = "-90" ></RotateTransform >
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform >
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <!--<Canvas.Resources>
        </Canvas.Resources>-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="115" Canvas.Top="440" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Label Margin="10,30,0,30" TabIndex="20" x:Name="Label1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Enter Text:" 
                   Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource LabelStyle}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.511,-2.5"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtText" TabIndex="0" Width="200" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" MinLines="1"
                MaxLines="3" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="40,10,0,10"   
                BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" ToolTip="Type in message and hit enter to save postcard" KeyUp="txtText_KeyUp"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnFont" Content="Font" Width="75" Margin="45,35" Click="btnFont_Click" 
                    Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonStyle}}" IsDefault="True" Height="40" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Canvas.Top="570" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="40" x:Name="btnEmail" Width="75" Content="Email" IsEnabled="false" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonStyle}}" />
            <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="40" x:Name="btnCancel" Width="75" Content="Cancel" Click="btnCancel_Click" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonStyle}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
        private void btnFont_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FontDialog fontDialog1 = new FontDialog();  // try setting initial color here
        fontDialog1.ShowColor = true;
        
        var result = fontDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Drawing.Color fc = fontDialog1.Color;

            txtText.FontFamily = new swm.FontFamily(fontDialog1.Font.Name);
            txtText.FontSize = fontDialog1.Font.Size;
            txtText.FontWeight = FontWeight = fontDialog1.Font.Bold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Regular;
            txtText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(fc.A, fc.R, fc.G, fc.B));

            //tblkText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(fc.A, fc.R, fc.G, fc.B));

            var bindingExpression = tblkText.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

            bindingExpression = tblkText.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

            bindingExpression = tblkText.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

            bindingExpression = tblkText.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

            bindingExpression = tblkText.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

            //(FindResource("LabelStyle") as Style).Resources.; 
            //(FindResource("LabelStyle") as Style).;     // as Label).ref ();

            bindingExpression = Label1.GetBindingExpression(Label.StyleProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

            bindingExpression = btnFont.GetBindingExpression(Button.StyleProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

            bindingExpression = btnEmail.GetBindingExpression(Button.StyleProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

            bindingExpression = btnCancel.GetBindingExpression(Button.StyleProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

    }
}
```

app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="PostcardMVVM.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PostcardMVVM"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

Screen shot of postcard form in correct state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
txtText.FontWeight = FontWeight = fontDialog1.Font.Bold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Regular;
```

Has an extra `FontWeight=` which will set **the Parent form** to bold. And its child controls, including your buttons, will inherit its boldness.

Getting rid of the extraneous setter should fix it.

Comment: Doh! that totally slipped by me. it's not even the proper form of a ternary operation - at least not the way i was using it. Thanx..

Comment: @gmes29 it's annoying that `a = b = c` is valid in most C-like language. When not being abused to make code harder to read, they contribute to accidents like this.